# Drawing to a GDI+ Bitmap

Tags: c++, gdi+, hbitmap

I am trying to move everything from GDI to GDI+. As it stands I am drawing to a buffer DC (GDI). I am wanting to have it instead drawn to a HBITMAP and only have it drawn once. I have tried 
things with pointers and Image, but could not find anything useful. There is no istream or file, and I am not using the flat api version (found a constructor for that.)

http://pastebin.com/bcw07Suq

Comment: If you want to move to GDI+ then stop using HBITMAPs.  A "buffer DC" ought to be a Bitmap, preferably in the 32bppPARGB pixel format to make it fast.  You draw into it with Graphics::FromImage().  But if you need it then you go from a HBITMAP to a Bitmap with Bitmap::FromHBITMAP().

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved. Here is how you can create the bitmap and then proceed to draw.

```
Graphics g(hDC);
Bitmap foobar(100,100,PixelFormat32bppPARGB);
g.DrawImage(&foobar,100,100);
SolidBrush brush(Color::Blue);
g.FillRectangle(&brush, 0,0,10,10);
```